# Unclickable Navigation on interior pages of website

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, navigation

I have been working on a site for a client but ran into a strange issue with a theme i purchased. On the interior pages the navigation becomes unclickable. Using firebug i noticed it keeps throwing a jquery error. I have no idea what it means though. I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction.

http://www.1000degreespizza.com/franchise-faqs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Chrome dev tools, you can see where the error come from:

[image]

From site.js, line 184:

```
(window).on("scroll", function(){
    // Distance from section to top
    var x = $(".contentsection.story").offset().top;
```

The selector  `$(".contentsection.story")` doesn't seem to be valid: there is no contentsection element with the story class in your DOM. So you try to access the top properties of `$(".contentsection.story").offset()`, which return undefined and throw a TypeError.

I let you solve the problem, now you know where it comes ;)